# Regex-guided crawler that downloads regex-matching images up to a crawling level

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

This is one simple crawler that downloads images from websites, the website's URL to be crawled to must match the regex, as well as any image-to-download's URL.

(Also, I know, I made my own thread pool, because I did want to keep my crawler lightweight...)

Code:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json
import os.path
import urlparse
import os
import ntpath
import urllib
import threading
import Queue
import time


class MultiThreadQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, max_simultaneous_threads):
        self.thread_queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.max_simultaneous_threads = max_simultaneous_threads
        self.executing_threads = 0
        self._threads_executed = []

    def add_thread(self, thread):
        return self.thread_queue.put(thread)

    def set_max_simultaneous_threads(self, max_simultaneous_threads):
        self.max_simultaneous_threads = max_simultaneous_threads

    def execute_last_thread(self):
        if self.executing_threads >= self.max_simultaneous_threads:
            return False

        thread = self.thread_queue.get_nowait()
        self._threads_executed.append(thread)
        self._threads_executed[-1].start()
        self.executing_threads += 1
        return True

    def execute_threads(self):
        if self.max_simultaneous_threads == 0:
            while True:
                try:
                    self.thread_queue.get().start()

                except Queue.Empty:
                    return

            return

        while True:
            try:
                if self.execute_last_thread():
                    thread = self._threads_executed[-1]
                    threading.Thread(name="Temporary internal TJT", target=self._join_thread, args=(thread,)).start()

                if self.executing_threads < 1:
                    return True

                else:
                    time.sleep(0.05)

            except Queue.Empty:
                return True

    def _join_thread(self, thread):
        thread.join()
        self.executing_threads -= 1


def regex(value, reg):
    if reg == "":
        return True

    return bool(re.search(reg, value))


def ends_with_any(string, list_of_endings):
    for ending in list_of_endings:
        if string.endswith(ending):
            return True

    return False


def fetch_from_url(link_url, regex_filter, crawl_filter, max_level=5, this_level=0):
    if max_level < 1 or max_level < this_level:
        print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Bug: Max level reached in this URL iteration and function called anyways!"
        return []

    images = []
    request = requests.get(link_url)

    if request.status_code != 200:
        print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Status code {} received! Leaving this crawl.".format(request.status_code)
        return []

    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(request.text)
    print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Fetching images at {}!".format(link_url)

    for image in soup.findAll("img", {"src": True}):
        print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Trying image {}!".format(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, image["src"]))
        if not regex(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, image["src"]), regex_filter):
            print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Image's path does not match with the regex {}!".format(regex_filter)
            continue

        print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Appending image at {}!".format(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, image["src"]))
        images.append(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, image["src"]))

    if max_level > 0:
        for link in soup.findAll("a", {"href": True}):
            if ends_with_any(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, link["href"]).lower(),
                             ("png", "jpeg", "jpg", "tga", "gif", "bmp", "jpng")):
                print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Got image from sudden link {}!".format(
                    urlparse.urljoin(link_url, link["href"]))

                if not regex(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, link["href"]), regex_filter):
                    print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Image's path does not match with the regex {}!".format(
                        regex_filter)
                    continue

                images.append(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, link["href"]))

                continue

            print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Crawling to {}!".format(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, link["href"]))

            if regex(urlparse.urljoin(link_url, link["href"]), crawl_filter):
                images += fetch_from_url(
                    urlparse.urljoin(link_url, link["href"]),
                    regex_filter,
                    crawl_filter,
                    max_level - 1,
                    this_level + 1
                )

                continue

            print "|" + ("-" * this_level) + "Crawling path does not match with the regex {}!".format(crawl_filter)

    return images


def download(url, result_file, rewrite_file=False):
    print "Downloading from {} into {}!".format(url, result_file)

    if os.path.exists(result_file) and not rewrite_file:
        print "File already exists!"
        return False

    urllib.urlretrieve(url, result_file)
    print "Download from {} succesful! File available at {}.".format(url, result_file)
    return True


if __name__ != "__main__":
    exit()

parsed = json.load(open("texlibs.json"))

downloads = MultiThreadQueue(parsed[1])

for image_kind_or_folder, (url, regex_filter, crawl_filter, max_level) in parsed[0].items():
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join("../result", image_kind_or_folder)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join("../result", image_kind_or_folder))

    print "Looking for images in specified URL!"

    for image in fetch_from_url(url, regex_filter, crawl_filter, max_level):
        result_path = "../{}/{}".format(os.path.join("result", image_kind_or_folder), ntpath.basename(image))

        downloads.add_thread(
            threading.Thread(
                name="Download \'{} -> {}\' Thread".format(image, result_path),
                target=download,
                args=(image, result_path)
            )
        )

print "Downloading all appended images!"

downloads.execute_threads()
```

(also avaiable on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Gustavo6046/Minimcrawler))

Comment: What was wrong with `if __name__ == "__main__" `? Why make your script not importable?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Wasn't it importable already? It just won't import past the `if __name__ != "__main__": exit()`?

Comment: Did you try to `import <your_script>` before making such claim?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I weren't claiming, but you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos for choosing a terrific HTML parser. I recommend invoking version 4.6 in this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Using `any()` could turn `ends_with_any()` into a (perfectly clear) one-liner.

In `fetch_from_url`, the default keyword args are perfect. I would love to see a docstring for the function. I'm reading a `return []` a few times, which gives me a hint about its signature, but I'd much rather see the function's author put a stake in the sand. `download()`'s `rewrite_file=False` is also nicely readable.

From the `print` I see you're using python2. Maybe consider 3? Also, maybe this explains the use of downrev BeautifulSoup.

The expression `"|" + ("-" * this_level)` appears a few times, which suggests the opportunity to define a helper function. If you nest it within `fetch_from_url` then you won't even have to pass in `this_level` as an explicit argument.

Repeated copy-n-paste calls to urljoin suggest that you may want to cache results in temp variables.

The code starting with `parsed = json.load ...` looks like it wants be wrapped within `def main()`, as Mathias observed. Always strive for `import` to silently succeed, just in case someone wants to reuse your code later. It's too easy, may as well just do it, it's very low hanging fruit.

`image_kind_or_folder` is nicely descriptive, and so is this:

```
    downloads = MultiThreadQueue(parsed[1])
```

You had an opportunity to name `parsed[0]` there, as well, so the Gentle Reader would understand what sort of dict it is.

The `set_max_simultaneous_threads` setter is an anti-pattern, and is not used, recommend you delete it, looks like the ctor has that covered already. Please add a docstring to the constructor - the semantics of `max_simultaneous_threads == 0` are not obvious.

`execute_threads()` works for you, so I'll mostly refrain from criticizing it, but `_threads_executed` seems a little odd, perhaps `_threads_executing` would be more natural (so `_join_thread()` would delete an entry). That way you could use `len()` rather than maintaining the `executing_threads` count.

Comment: "_Kudos for using the best HTML parser ever_". That's subjective. Best in what way?

Comment: Sorry, I got a little carried away. I was just trying to validate OP's choice of parser. I find Beautiful Soup is a do-what-I-mean kind of library. It's robust to ugly HTML spec. violations, and lets your code blissfully believe that other HTML authors do sane things, like following nesting rules. I downgraded to merely "terrific".